# are sockets (socket.io) context based?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a back-end server (Nodejs + Express) and front-end clients (reactjs).

I would like to implement sockets to replace some APIs.

I'm using `socket.io` for the back-end and `socket.oi-client` for the front.

My question is when clients establish a connection to the server via sockets, do they each run in their own context?

```
io.on(
    "connection",
    socketioJwt.authorize({
      secret: process.env.secretKey,
      timeout: 15000 // 15 seconds to send the authentication message
    })
  ).on("authenticated", socket => {
    console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} connected.`);

    socket.on("myEvent", async request => {
      try {      
        // update resource in database
        socket.broadcast.emit("updated", {
          // data
        });
      } catch (e) {
        // log error in database
        io.emit("onError", {
          // e.message
        });
      }
    });
```

Given the above code - if two clients were to emit an event to `myEvent` , wouldn't the latter overwrite the former's data in the database?

Comment: It depends upon how you are handling your socket.on in server

Comment: Could you please elaborate?